# No easy 14.04 dual setup

Tags: boot, windows-7

I started with win7 and ubuntu 13.10. I attempted an upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 but it failed to reboot (see my earlier question for the blackscreen output). Fortunately, I am still able to boot win7, and I have since removed ubuntu with the idea to do a fresh install of 14.04. Should I wait a few weeks until all the numerous problems I am reading about 14.04 are resolved? I don't want to risk messing up my win7.

Comment: Could you post some links to the problems you've been hearing about please? Then we can see better if they are likely to apply to you or not. (And possibly your system specs if the problems are system specific).

Answer (score 0):

Back up your Windows 7 and make sure you have your activation key written down and you can burn a Windows 7 boot disk if you need to (ask in the comments below if you want specific help with this).

Then overwrite 13.10 with 14.04. I think it's highly unlikely that this will mess with Windows 7 if you make sure you click 'Delete 13.10 and Install 14.04' (or similar) in the install menu. The only possible problem is that GRUB might break on upgrade and then you won't be able to boot (which is when your Windows 7 backup/disk/key will come in useful) but I don't think this is very likely.